# Delay on file read on newly created file in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, express

[image: App.get]

[image: fs.write]

I am writing a new *json* file when I run my **results.html** page and then using express.static to make the public folder files accessible in the browser.

I have my app working but am having to click the button multiple times in order to have the updated file be written and accessed.

How should I send the **JSON** info to the browser without writing a file? Or not experience this lag?

Comment: try to use POST instead?

Comment: Those are literally **TWO LINES** of code! Can't you actually **include** them instead of using a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Send the data back in response

```
function setData(req, res) {
    var data = '';

    req.on('data', function(streamData) {
        data += streamData;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        fs.writeFile('data/data.json', data, 'utf8', function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                res.writeHead(201, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/json'
                });
                res.end(data)
            } else {
                res.writeHead(400, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/json'
                });
                res.end("File write error" + err)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

access the data from front end

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/set/data',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data
    })
    .done(function(responseData) {
        // update your ui with responseData
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```